# I have a polynomial equation and Y, How can I find X?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, equation

Consider it:

```
X = [1, 2, 3]
p = np.poly1d(X)
print('x: ', X, 'y: ', p(X))
```

> `output >> x: [1, 2, 3] y: [ 6 11 18]`

what if I want to find `x` based on `y`?

> `x: [?, ?, ?] y: [ 6 11 18]`

Comment: Sounds like a question for `math.stackexchange.com` - inverse polynomials (of higher magnitudes) are extremely difficult. EDIT: also, are you defining your function coeff as X then inputting X?

Comment: Maybe something like [numpy.roots](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html)

Answer (score 0):

`np.poly1d(X)` means you create a polynomial of the required degree where `X` are its coefficients. Let's call them a, b, and c. So practically you have the expression

```
a*x**2 + b*x + c
```

When you then pass these three values for `x`, you get the following 3 equations

```
a**3 + b*a + c = 6
a*b**2 + b**2 + c = 11
a*c**2 + b*c + c = 18
```

There might be an algebraic way you can solve them yourself, but after a quick think I didn't come up with anything. However, sympy will happily solve this system of equations for you.

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym

def generate_y(X):
    return np.poly1d(X)(X)

def solve_x(Y):
    a, b, c = sym.symbols('a b c')
    e1 = sym.Eq(a**3 + b*a + c, Y[0])
    e2 = sym.Eq(a*b**2 + b**2 + c, Y[1])
    e3 = sym.Eq(a*c**2 + b*c + c, Y[2])
    return sym.solvers.solve([e1, e2, e3], [a, b, c])
```

For example

```
>>> solve_x(generate_y([1, 2, 3]))
[(1, 2, 3)]
>>> solve_x(generate_y([-5, 105, 2]))
[(-5, 105, 2)]
```

---

You could generalise this for nth order polynomials by creating the symbolic expressions dynamically, but for higher order you'll run into problems (such is life) and for 1st order you'll have multiple solutions.

```
def solve_x(Y):
    symbols = sym.symbols('a:z')[:len(Y)]
    X = sym.symbols('X')
    expr = sum(s*X**i for i, s in enumerate(symbols[::-1]))
    eqns = [sym.Eq(expr.subs({X: s}), y) for s, y in zip(symbols, Y)]
    return sym.solvers.solve(eqns, symbols)
```

Usage

```
>>> solve_x(generate_y([1, 2]))
[(1, 2), (-1 + sqrt(2), 2*sqrt(2)), (-sqrt(2) - 1, -2*sqrt(2))]
>>> solve_x(generate_y([1, 2, 3, 4]))
# still computing...
```